# C# ListView search item without clear list

Tags: c#, sorting, listview, search

I have winform project on C# platform. I have listview and textbox as you see in pic below.
I want to reorder the list according to the text value entered by the user.

I researched before ask here, I generally saw solutions based on removing and re-adding all units to listview again. I don't want to do that because my listview has too many items with pictures so removing and re-adding items causes listview to work slowly.

What I want is that,  when the user enters characters in the textbox, the items which starts with this characters, bring this items the top of the list something similar google search system.

I tried the codes below but this send the item at the end of the list even though i chose index 0.
Thanx.

[image]

```
private void txt_search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = txt_search.Text;
            var item = listView1.FindItemWithText(text);
            if (item != null)
            {
                int index = listView1.Items.IndexOf(item);

                if (index > 0)
                {
                    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
                    listView1.Items.Insert(0, item);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Consider using the ListView in _Virtual Mode_ for better performance when you have a large list to display. You'll be able to do better filtering/sorting routines because you have a control over the data is being displayed.

Comment: @Fixations answer worked for me. Thanx for attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` is sorted using the `.Sort()` function, not sure what the default behaviour is, but I think you need a custom comparer.

Here is an example implementation by (ab)using the `ListViewItem.Tag`.

Custom Comparer:

```
private class SearchCompare : Comparer<ListViewItem>
{
    public override int Compare(ListViewItem x, ListViewItem y)
    {
        if (x?.Tag != null && y?.Tag != null)
        {
            return x.Tag.ToString().CompareTo(y.Tag.ToString());
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Initializing the `ListView`:

```
var items = new[]
{
    "1 no",
    "2 yes",
    "3 no",
    "4 yes"
};
foreach (var item in items)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new SearchCompare(); // custom sorting
```

And ofcourse the text changed event handler:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = textBox1.Text;
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Text.IndexOf(text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
        {
            item.Tag = "a"; // a is sorted before b
        }
        else
        {
            item.Tag = "b"; // b is sorted after a
        }
    }
    listView1.Sort();
}
```

Typing "yes" in the search textbox will sort items 2 and 4 in front of items 1 and 3.

Comment: Firstly, thanx for attention and your time. It is worked but i removed [AllowNull]. because app can not define it. If I do this, will it cause problems in the future? (see pic) [link](https://ibb.co/6gQy34n)

Comment: Those are custom annotations for code profiling purposes, i dont even notice them anymore. I editted the question and removed those aswell.